# Kendo MVVM scheduler template for agenda

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, scheduler

I have this code...

```
    $(function() {
    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
      date: new Date("2015/1/1"),
      views: [
        {
          type: "agenda",
          eventTemplate: $("#event-template").html()
        },
      ],
      dataSource: [
        {
          id: 1,
          start: new Date("2015/1/1 08:00 AM"),
          end: new Date("2015/1/1 09:00 AM"),
          title: "Test",
          atendees: [1]
        }
      ],
      resources: [
        {
          field: "atendees",
          dataSource: [
           { value: 1, text: "Jim" },
          ],
          multiple: true
        }
      ]
    }).data("kendoScheduler");

    $("#scheduler").on("click", ".edit-event",function() {
      var dataItem = scheduler.occurrenceByUid($(this).data("uid"));

      scheduler.editEvent(dataItem);
    });
  });
```

which works fine, but I am moving over to an MVVM approach can anyone help me get my new MVVM code to accept a template for my agenda view please. Code I have is

```
    <script id="event-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <div class="edit-event" data-uid="#=uid#">
            <div><b>Job</b>: #: title #</div>
            <div>
                <b>Staff:</b>
                # for (var i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) { #
                #: resources[i].text #
                # } #
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
<div id="topper">
        <div class="demo-section k-header wide">
            <div>
                <div data-role="scheduler" data-views="['agenda','month']" data-bind="source: tasks, visible: isVisible, events: { save: onSave }" data-template="event-template"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Which does not work - doesn't crash, it just doesn't load the template I am also aware that this approach may use the template for all views not just agenda. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same behavior in MVVM you should define the view as object inside the "data-views" option:

```
 <div data-role="scheduler" 
      data-views="['agenda',{ type: 'agenda', eventTemplate: $('\#event-template').html() }]" 
      data-bind="source: tasks, visible: isVisible, events: { save: onSave }"
      data-template="event-template"></div>
```